# SharePoint End to End Development

Tags: sharepoint, development-environment

How do you use SharePoint as an end-to-end developer platform?

1. Which Source control software do you use typically. SourceSafe/TFS or any other source control software?
2. Which end to end development tools/methodologies do you use?
3. When do you allow SPD as development platform, and how do you maintain the site working with SPD?
4. What the best practices for coding that you follow?
5. How do you handle adding new web services?

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Each of your question deserves a separate thread :). If you are new to SP, don't bother about 1,3 & 5. Concentrate on 2 and 4. I dont want to give specific links for resource since there are abundant of them out there. The best place to start with is MSDN.

Comment: Hi Kyle,

Thanks for commenting. I am not really new to SharePoint, but I was still curious about how others are doing it currently. 

I will make a more precise question next time around :-) Quite new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our organization, we use the following:

1. Subversion, with [AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)
2. VS 2008 is our IDE (SPD for Development is bad) and Scrum/Agile.  For builds/deployments we use [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) and [SharePoint Installer](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller)
3. Be careful with SPD.  In our organization, we restrict who is even allowed to download and install it.
4. Use [SPDisposeCheck](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck) to double check your code to avoid disposing of objects when not needed, or to double check that you did dispose of what needs to be disposed of.
5. We have configured a separate IIS website on the the SharePoint WFEs to host custom web services that use the object model.  Those that don't use the object model are hosted elsewhere.

Comment: For #4, there is already many articles on technet on SharePoint best practices: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/office/dd638301(en-us).aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. We use TFS because we have a group in our company that supports the TFS Server.  If this group did not exist I do not believe we would use this tool.
2. Visual Studio 2008 / Aspects of Extreme Programming and Agile.
3. Never, we view SharePoint Designer as evil.  We do everything through custom developed programs or scripts.
4. Consistency, Consistency, Consistency...  we have some common sense practices that have come from many places (Software Craftmanship Movement, MS Patterns and Practices and experiance).
5. We have managed to avoid integrating Web Services into our SharePoint solution.